# Init spring boot mocks before they are injected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Is there a way to initialise mocks before they are injected into another component?

To give an example I have following classes:

```java
@Service
SomeService {
    @Autowired
    public SomeService(SomeConfig config)
}

@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class SomeConfig {
  private String someValue;
}
```

In my test I'm doing the following:

```java
@MockBean
SomeConfig someConfig;

@Autowired
SomeService someService;
```

The problem is, that the `SomeService` constructor is already accessing `SomeConfig` members, before I can even initialise it with `when(someConfig.getSomeValue()).thenReturn("something")`, resulting in a `NullPtrException`.

Is there a hook that gets executed before `SomeService` is instantiated?

Comment: In your test shouldn't you do `@InjectMocks` on `SomeService` instead of `@Autowired`?

Comment: Can you include your test method so we have more context about what you are trying to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manually setup your Service in a setup method.
Just make sure to exclude your SomeService from classpath scanning in those tests.

```java
SomeServiceTest {
  @MockBean
  SomeConfig someConfig;

  SomeService someService;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup(){
    // init mocks
    // setup other stuff

    someService = new SomeService(someConfig);
  }

}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: another way would be to define a TestConfig class that contains the (mocked) beans. you could then import that TestConfig in your test-context. But I dont think that it's a more elgant way. But depends on your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the SomeService  looks like:

```
@Service
SomeService {

    private final SomeConfig config

    @Autowired
    public SomeService(SomeConfig config) {
       this.someConfig = someConfig;
       // some logic with config getters
    }
}
```

You should use annotation
@PostConsturct in a separate method and put the usage of config getters there, like:

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
// some logic with config getters
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to achieve that w/o changing production code but this sounds like a pretty good solution. Will give it a try.